# How to reroute nested resource or rename nested resource in Cake 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Right now, when I use nested resources like this:

```
 $routes->resources('Events', function ($routes) {
    $routes->resources('EventTicketSales');
});
```

That means when I need to use the route `/events/:event_id/event_ticket_sales` and this route will go to `EventTicketSalesController` and the action `index`.

I was wondering whether it is possible to route `/events/:event_id/event_ticket_sales` to a different action because I also needed to serve `/event_ticket_sales` with different display and the logic is getting a bit too thick and confusing for that single action to be used.

Meaning to say,

I have different logic for `/event_ticket_sales` and `/events/:event_id/event_ticket_sales`. And both use the index action.

That's why I want to have separate actions for each endpoint.

Another question is if there is a way for me to rename all the nested routes into `/events/:event_id/sales` instead of `/events/:event_id/event_ticket_sales`

Comment: How would connecting the default route to a different action solve the problem of the action having "too much logic"?

Comment: I have different logic for `/event_ticket_sales` and `/events/:event_id/event_ticket_sales`. And both use the index action currently.

That's why I want to have separate actions for each endpoint.

Comment: try Learn Graphql, then you will forget all that old rest methods

Comment: cool thanks for pointing me to graphql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

- Split your logic into "indexStandalone" and "indexNested" protected methods.
- In your index action method check if event_id has been passed as a parameter.
- If event_id was in params - call indexNested, otherwise call indexStandalone.

Hope this helps!